# Custom message when requesting user's permission to Contacts

Tags: ios, contactsui

I'm using this code to request access to the Contacts UI:

```
        let store = CNContactStore()
        store.requestAccess(for: .contacts) { (granted, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
            if granted {
                completionHandler(.granted)
            } else {
                completionHandler(.denied)
            }
        }
```

But I want to show a custom message in the alert pop up that shows up, detailing why I need to access the user's contacts. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into your `Info.plist` file, add the following key `NSContactsUsageDescription`, and add your custom alert message in the value field.

Comment: I found a key called "Privacy - Contacts Usage Description" in plist, that's what I needed to change to make the text appear. Thanks!

Comment: @Rod that's the `NSContactsUsageDescription` key--the property list automatically converts it into something more readable when you add it